# Masonry issues at certain viewport sizes

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, image, jquery-masonry

I'm using Masonry and Lazy load to create a responsive masonry gallery, I have come across an issue, everything is fine but some viewport sizes seem to add a large white space to the left, I might jut be being blind but if anyone could have a look it'd be appreciated, this is the page its on

- http://www.venetianorrington.com/weddings/weddings/

JS -

```
var $container = $('#masonry');
   $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
   $container.masonry({
   itemSelector: '.item',
});
 $('.item img').addClass('not-loaded');
 $('.item img.not-loaded').lazyload({
 effect: 'fadeIn',
load: function() {
// Disable trigger on this image
    $(this).removeClass("not-loaded");
    $container.masonry('reload');
}
 });
 $('.item img.not-loaded').trigger('scroll');
});
```

Thanks alot, Harry.

Comment: whitespace left or right?

Comment: On the right, if you slowly resize the page you'll hit a point at which it happens.

Comment: Okay, i've just updated masonry which seems to of fixed it, but now I have an issue with the images when you scroll past the first load of images.